# Unable to find data path while launching mongod.exe

Tags: mongodb

So, I know there are tons of questions generically on this issue, but I could not find answer to what I was looking for.

I installed MongoDB 4.4.5 on C:\devworld\mongo on Windows 10. Here is the db location specified in cfg

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\devworld\mongo\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

The folder specified is the default (once I setup C:\devworld\mongo as my install folder).

When I start mongod.exe, I get this error:

```
"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\\data\\db\\
```

My first question is:
**(1) From where is it picking up this path C:\data\db\**

Then, I went on to try something what docs suggested. In a cmd window (as administrator). I setup a new data folder:

> mongod.exe --dbpath c:\dbdata\mongo

I see all the files getting created in the folder.

My next question is **(2) Why do I not see .cfg getting updated with the new path?**
And my last question is **(3) Even after all that, when I run mongod.exe, I still get the same error  C:\data\db\ not found. Why?**

Answer (score 0):

When you run just `mongod.exe` without `-f` or `--config` option then it does not read your config file and thus uses the default dbPath `C:\data\db\` - which does not exist.

Comment: so then why wouldn't mongod.exe --dbpath help?

Comment: It does. "You write `mongod.exe --dbpath c:\dbdata\mongo` -> I see all the files getting created in the folder." That's all like expected. However, I prefer to use a config file for all settings instead of command line options. Of course data goes into `c:\dbdata\mongo` instead of `C:\devworld\mongo\data`

Comment: So, yes, I  did use mongod.exe --dbpath c:\dbdata\mongo. And yes, all files were created. However, my issue is launching the server "mongod.exe" does not see that change. It still continues to search for C:\data\db\ instead of c:\dbdata\mongo. And BTW --config now raises another alert "log" folder not accessible (even though the log folder exists). Seems to me creating C:\data\db\  is a simple option, but that puts the underlying issue under the rug

Comment: The dbPath setting is not stored at any place. You have to specify it every time you start `mongod.exe`, either as option or by the config file.